# Encryption after Symlinks are made

Tags: linux, symlink, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I wanted to ask before I did something really stupid. So, here it goes...

.

Here's the components I will be referencing:

- "LinuxOS" Partition (dedicated disk; no other partitions on the disk)
- "MyFiles" Partition (dedicated disk; no other partitions on the disk)
- Encryption
- Symlinks

.

Here's the setup:

- "LinuxOS" only has the OS.
- "LinuxOS" has symlinks pointing to folders on "MyFiles".

.

**My Question:** Will encrypting the entire disk with "LinuxOS" on it then also encrypt all the contents that it's symlinks point to on the "My Files" partition and/or disk?

Comment: How are you going to encrypt the disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are strictly using disk encryption at the hardware layer then no. However if you are using a encryption program that does the encryption file to file and have it set so it follows symlinks then it should encrypt the file the link points at.